# Difference between upper class and inherited class pointing while assigning same class

Tags: c++, class, variable-assignment

While I studying C++ personally, I doubt about assigning pointer to classes. For example:

```
 43 int main () {
 44     View *window = new View ("window");
 45     Render *renderer; // why Render(upper class) points subclass and it works?
 46     renderer = new Print;
 47     renderer->draw (window); // this renderer works like Print function. why?
 48 
 49     //what are the difference between up and down?
 50     Print *a;
 51     a = new Print;
 52     a->draw (window);
 53     return 0;
 54 }
```

For your information, `Render` is class, and `Print` is subclass of `Render`. However, as you see in line 46, Upper class points subclass and it works with no error.

So, I also tried pointing `Print` class and call `draw` function in line 52. It works with no error.

I have no idea that what difference are those and why it works without errors or warnings.

Comment: It works because that is the way the language is designed. This should be covered in any introductory C++ book. Note that you have memory leaks though: each `new` requires a `delete`.

Comment: This is polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate an inherited class, also its base object gets instantiated. This is polymorphism. I think you should read through [Virtual Functions C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html).

Comment: Then is there any kind of assigning warning occurred? For example it looks like `int *a;` assigning `a = float b;`

Comment: This is not the same, since `Print` is *inherited* from `Render`, thus they are *related*. `int` and `float` are not related. Furthermore, it seems to me, that you did not really understand pointers.

Comment: I could not catch concept of _related_. And the last question, I understood that is really silly question that is because of its address size.

Comment: The suggestion is to grab a *good* C++ beginners book and carefully read through the inheritance chapter.

Comment: Appreciate of your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have reference of parent class to the object of child class. Using this reference you can call only those functions for which parent class is aware i.e. only those methods which are present in parent class.

By using the reference of parent class, the reference can be refer to any other child class object also.

Comment: Your comment _the reference can be refer to any other child class object also_ means variable `renderer` can points any other subclass?

Comment: I appreciate of your help. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It works because `Print` is a subclass of `Render` and the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) holds.

`renderer->draw(window)` effectively calls `Print::draw` because `Render::draw` is a virtual function. If it weren't declared a `virtual`, `Render::draw` would have been called instead.

Difference is, that you cannot store `renderer` in a `std::vector<Print*>` even though `renderer` points to a `Print`. Another difference is that `Print` may hide methods of `Render`. The hidden methods are not as easily accessible in `a` as they are in `renderer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a pointer to `Render` and assigning it the address of a `Print` object that is created on the heap. Since `Print` is derived from `Render`, this is a legal assignment.

The compiler sees `renderer` only as a `Render` object and so looks to the `Render` object to find the `draw()` method.